# Gratis Windows spreadsheet which supports 64 bit integer values and has charting

Tags: windows, gratis, spreadsheet

Important: just because it is a 64-bit .EXE does not mean that it supports 64 bit integer values (I'm looking at you, Excel). If you don't understand what 64 bit precision is, please don't just Google & suggest something.

I am looking for a gratis spreadsheet which will:

- run on Windows
- support true 64 bit integer values  (with no floating point involved)
- support charting of those values

Comment: by 64 bit values, do you mean 64 bit FP or 64 bit integers?  According to [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/69797/why-is-dec2bin-limited-to-82bits-in-an-32-and-64-bits-world/) libreOffice uses 64 bit FP for its number storage system

Comment: Sorry, I meant 64 bit integers (FP is the spawn of Beelzebub). I have updated the question (and upvoted your comment).

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate it.  Agree floating point is from the evil one!